# TodoList с папками

Tags: javascript, html, app

У меня есть простенький ToDoList на js. Нужно добавить возможность группировать задачи по папкам. То есть изначально мы добавляем общую задачу, а после в нее добавляем подзадачи, пытался что-то найти, но не смог. Если есть идеи или может видели подобный функционал буду рад любой информации.
[image: ToDoList]

```js
let $addMessage = document.querySelector(".message");
let $addButton = document.querySelector(".add");
let $todo = document.querySelector(".todo");
let $delete = document.querySelector(".delete");
let $removeAll = document.querySelector(".remove_all");
let $removeFinish = document.querySelector(".remove_finish");
let $countTask = document.querySelector("#count");
let $countFinish = document.querySelector("#count-finish");

let todoList = [];

const toDay = () => {
  let today = new Date().toLocaleString();
  return today;
};

const addNewTodo = () => {
  let newTodo = {
    id: null,
    todo: $addMessage.value,
    category: null,
    checked: false,
    important: false,
    time: toDay(),
  };

  todoList.push(newTodo);

  renderMessages();

  localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(todoList));

  $addMessage.value = "";
  disableButton($addButton);
};

$addMessage.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  let allInputsFilled = false;

  if (!!event.target.value.trim().length) {
    allInputsFilled = true;
  }

  if (allInputsFilled) {
    enableButton($addButton);
  } else {
    disableButton($addButton);
  }
});

$addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  addNewTodo();
});

const renderMessages = () => {
  let message = "";
  let countTask = 0;

  if (todoList.length === 0) $todo.innerHTML = "";
  todoList.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.id = i;
    message += `
        <li class=${item.checked ? "checked" : ""}>
        <label for="item_${i}" class="checkbox ${
      item.important ? "important" : ""
    }">
        <input class="checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="item_${i}" ${
      item.checked ? "checked" : ""
    }>
        <span class="checkbox-check"></span>
        <div class="checkbox-text">
        ${item.todo}
        </div>
      </label>
      <div class="delete" data-id="delete-${i}"></div>
      <time>${item.time}</time>
      </li>
        `;

    $todo.innerHTML = message;
  });

  countTask = todoList.length;

  let countFinish = () => {
    const arryFinish = todoList.filter((item) => {
      return item.checked === false;
    });
    return todoList.length - arryFinish.length;
  };

  $countTask.innerHTML = `${countTask}`;
  $countFinish.innerHTML = `${countFinish()}`

  if (countTask >= 3) {
    enableButton($removeAll);
  } else {
    disableButton($removeAll);
  }

  if (countFinish() >= 1) {
    enableButton($removeFinish);
  } else {
    disableButton($removeFinish);
  }
};

$todo.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  let inputId = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute("id").match(/\d+/));

  todoList.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.id === inputId) {
      item.checked = !item.checked;
      localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(todoList));
    }
  });

  renderMessages();
});

$todo.addEventListener("contextmenu", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  todoList.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.todo === event.target.innerHTML.trim()) {
      item.important = !item.important;
      renderMessages();
      localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(todoList));
    }
  });
});

$todo.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target.hasAttribute("data-id")) {
    todoList.splice(
      parseInt(event.target.getAttribute("data-id").match(/\d+/)),
      1
    );
    renderMessages();
    localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(todoList));
  }
});

$removeAll.addEventListener("click", () => {
  todoList.splice(0, todoList.length);
  renderMessages();
  localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(todoList));
});

$removeFinish.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const arryFinish = todoList.filter((item) => {
    return item.checked === false;
  });

  todoList = arryFinish;
  renderMessages();
  localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(todoList));
  disableButton($removeFinish);
});

const enableButton = (e) => {
  e.disabled = false;
};

const disableButton = (e) => {
  e.disabled = true;
};

const pressEnter = () => {
  $addMessage.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (!!e.target.value.length) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        addNewTodo();
      }
    }
  });
};

if (localStorage.getItem("todo")) {
  todoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo"));
  renderMessages();
}

pressEnter();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #f2f5fa;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.todo_list {
    max-width: 400px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 40px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e5eeff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 23px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Commissioner-Medium', sans-serif;
}

.create_new_todo {
    text-align: center;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 54px;

    font-family: 'Commissioner-Regular', sans-serif;

    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #dbe5f3;

    box-sizing: border-box;

    outline: 0;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: 1px solid #4c6cdd;
}

button {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 16px 32px;

    width: max-content;
    cursor: pointer;

    background-color: #254ac7;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;

    border: 0;
}

button[disabled]{
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.todo {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.todo li {
    padding: 1em 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

.todo li:hover .delete{
  opacity: 1;
}

.todo li:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbe5f3;
}

.todo_list-footer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 10px;
}

.remove_all{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.remove_finish{
  padding: 10px;
}

/*************** Checkbox ***************/

.checkbox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .checkbox *,
  .checkbox *::before,
  .checkbox *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .checkbox-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .checkbox-check {
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #BDC6CD;
    margin-right: 8px;
  }
  .checkbox-check::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  .checkbox-input[type="checkbox"] + .checkbox-check {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .checkbox-input[type="checkbox"] + .checkbox-check::after {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    background-image: url(' https://gitlab.com/d.lapshin1/todolist-js/-/raw/main/assets/icons/check_white.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
  }
  .checkbox-input[type="radio"] + .checkbox-check {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  .checkbox-input[type="radio"] + .checkbox-check::after {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-left: -3px;
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  .checkbox-text {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
   .checkbox-input:checked + .checkbox-check {
    border-color: #254ac7;
    background: #254ac7;
  }
  .checkbox:hover .checkbox-input + .checkbox-check {
    border-color: #254ac7;
  }
   .checkbox-input:focus + .checkbox-check,
   .checkbox-input:focus-visible + .checkbox-check {
    border-color: #99D1FF;
    border-width: 2px;
  }
   .checkbox-input:checked:focus + .checkbox-check,
   .checkbox-input:checked:focus-visible + .checkbox-check {
    border-color: #99D1FF;
    background: #0C6ED6;
    border-width: 2px;
  }
   .checkbox-input:active + .checkbox-check {
    border-color: #0C6ED6;
  }
   .checkbox-input:checked:active + .checkbox-check {
    background: #0C6ED6;
  }
   .checkbox-input:disabled + .checkbox-check {
    border-color: #DEE3E8;
  }
   .checkbox-input:checked:disabled + .checkbox-check {
    border-color: #F2F2F2;
    background: #F2F2F2;
  }
   .checkbox-input:disabled ~ .checkbox-text {
    color: #BDC6CD;
  }
   .checkbox-input:checked:disabled ~ .checkbox-text {
    color: #BDC6CD;
  }

  .checked .checkbox-text{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }


.important .checkbox-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000 !important;
}

.delete{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url("https://gitlab.com/d.lapshin1/todolist-js/-/raw/main/assets/icons/dismiss.svg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

time{
  color: #a2b6db;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Commissioner-Regular', sans-serif;

  position: absolute;
  left: 28px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.count-task p{
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #64738e;
  margin: 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

   <div class="todo_list">
        <h1>ToDo list</h1>
       <div class="create_new_todo">
           <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Описание">
           <button class="add" disabled>Добавить</button>
       </div>

       <div class="nav_bar">
        <div class="count-task">
            <p>
                Всего задач: <span id="count-finish"></span>/<span id="count"></span>
            </p>

        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="wrapper">
           <ul class="todo"></ul>
       </div>

       <div class="todo_list-footer">
        <button class="remove_finish" disabled>
            Удалить выполненные
        </button>
        <button class="remove_all" disabled>
            Удалить все
        </button>
       </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Посмотрите [вот этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1451606/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b5), похоже это то, что вам нужно

Comment: Слушайте да, похоже это, то что нужно. Сейчас по подробнее ознакомлюсь.